# metric on the set of complex sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let X be the set of complex sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in \mathbb{C}$. Show that the transformation:

$$ d((a_n), (b_n)) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \frac{|a_n - b_n|}{1 + |a_n - b_n|}$$
for $ (a_n), (b_n) \in X$ defines a metric on X.

Now it's easy to see that d is non-negative, that it's value is zero if and only if (a_n) = (b_n), and that symmetry is given aswell. And it's kind of obvious that the given series never diverges. But I've been struggling with the triangle inequality so far. I've tried writing out $d((a_n), (b_n)) ≤ d((a_n), (c_n)) + d((c_n), (b_n))$ using the series definition given above, but that didn't lead anywhere so far. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x,y,z \geq 0$, note that, $\frac{x}{1+x+y}\leq \frac{x}{1+x}$ and similarly $\frac{y}{1+x+y}\leq \frac{y}{1+y}$. Adding them you will get $\frac{x+y}{1+x+y}\leq \frac{x}{1+x} +\frac{y}{1+y}$.

Now using triangle inequality, we have $|a_n - b_n|\leq |a_n-c_n| +|c_n-b_n|$. Now using the fact that $\frac{t}{1+t}$ is an increasing function in $t$,we have
\begin{align}
 \frac{|a_n-b_n|}{1+ |a_n-b_n|} &\leq &\frac{|a_n-c_n| +|c_n-b_n|}{1+|a_n-c_n| +|c_n-b_n|} \\
\end{align}
Now using the inequality $\frac{x+y}{1+x+y}\leq \frac{x}{1+x} +\frac{y}{1+y}$, for $x,y \geq 0$, we will have $\frac{|a_n-c_n| +|c_n-b_n|}{1+|a_n-c_n| +|c_n-b_n|} \leq \frac{|a_n-c_n|}{1+ |a_n-c_n|} +\frac{|c_n-b_n|}{1+ |c_n-b_n|}$.

Hence we get,

$\frac{|a_n-b_n|}{1+ |a_n-b_n|} \leq \frac{|a_n-c_n|}{1+ |a_n-c_n|} +\frac{|c_n-b_n|}{1+ |c_n-b_n|}$

Now take the corresponding partal sum and limit to get the desired triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $a,b,c > 0$ and $c \le a +b.$ Show

$$\frac{c}{1+c} \le \frac{a}{1+a} + \frac{b}{1+b}.$$

The fact that $x/(1+x)$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$ will be useful.